# Does Android WebDriver support set_page_load_timeout?

Tags: android, python, selenium, webdriver

Using python bindings, when I run

```
a = Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities.ANDROID)
a.set_page_load_timeout(5)
```

I get this error

```
WebDriverException: Message: u'pageLoadTimeout' ; Stacktrace: Method pageLoadTimeout threw an error in AndroidWebDriver.java
```

Answer (score 1):

I explored the Java code for the Android side of Android WebDriver. I discovered that the method that's supposed to handle setting page load timeout doesn't.  In fact, it explicitly throws an UnsupportedOperationException instead.

Comment: Julian, did you report this to the Selenium bug list http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list